# Nontrivial finite group with trivial group homologies?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, open-problems

I stumbled across this question in a seminar-paper a long time ago:

*Does there exist a positive integer* $N$ *such that if* $G$ *is a finite group with* $\bigoplus_{i=1}^NH_i(G)=0$ *then* $G=\lbrace 1\rbrace$?

I believe this to still be an open problem.  For $N=1$, any perfect group (ex: $A_5$) is a counterexample.  For $N=2$, the binary icosahedral group $SL_2(F_5)$ suffices (perfect group with periodic Tate cohomology).  And I found in one of Milgram's papers a result for $N=5$, the sporadic Mathieu group $M_{23}$.  Note that this question is answered for infinite groups, because we can always construct a topological space (hence a $BG$ for some discrete group $G$) with prescribed homologies.

**Is there another known group with a larger $N\ge 5$ before homology becomes nontrivial?

Are there any classifications of obstructions in higher homology groups?**

[[Edit]]:  Another view.   A group is $\textit{acyclic}$ if it has trivial integral homology.  There are no nontrivial finite acyclic groups.  Indeed, a result of Richard Swan says that a group with $p$-torsion has nontrivial mod-$p$ cohomology in infinitely many dimensions, hence nontrivial integral homology.

Comment: What do you mean about constructing a topological space with prescribed homologies, and then calling it 'a $BG$'. The homology of $BG$ can't be chosen or prescribed, it just is. And what, qualitatively, separates finite groups from infinite groups when constructing this so-called $BG$? Sorry if I'm being dense..

Comment: @ David - For a connected CW complex $X$ the classifying space of the based loop space of $X$, i.e., $B\Omega X$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$. One can therefore think of $X$ as a classifying space of some H-space and I believe Milnor gave a model which realizes $\Omega X$ as a topological group. This is what the OP may be implying although I'm not so sure!

Comment: @David: Dan Kan and I once wrote a paper constructing, for any finite CW complex $X$, a space $Y = K(G,1)$, where $G$ is a finitely generated group, and a  map $Y \rightarrow X$ which induces an isomorphism
in homology over the fundamental group of $X$.  So it can be done
with homology of $G$ in the algebraic sense.  But the construction
actually depends on having a way to "cone off" the homology of any
group within a bigger group. John Mather had proved that the group
of compactly supported homeomorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ is acyclic (in the algebraic sense)---same trick, I got it from that.

Comment: @Bill, ah, so in the question, the $G$ in $BG$ is not the $G$ in $H_i(G)$? That makes it clearer, even if not crystal.

Comment: @David: I think the point is that for every simply connected (to avoid dealing with the fundamental group) finite CW complex $X$ there exists a group $G$ such that $H_i(X) \cong H_i(BG)$ for every $i$. I have heard this result referred to as "morally, all homology is group homology." I think the point is that if I pick the homology groups I can construct a group $G$ s.t. the homology of the groups has the desired homology. (I hope I didn't screw this up)

Comment: (I should say that your choice of homology groups should not violate some sort of subtle homotopy theoretic condition that precludes it from being the homology of a finite CW complex.)

Comment: @David: for a discrete group, $BG = K(G,1)$ (as homotopy types), 
and the homology of the group is the same as the homology of this
space.  For a topological group, if $G_\delta$ denotes $G$ with discrete topology, then $K(G,1) = BG_\delta$, and often has quite
different homology from $BG$.  For instance $BSL_2(\mathbb R)$
is homotopy equivalent to $BSO_1$, which is $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$.
But $BSL_2(\mathbb R)_\delta$ has uncountably generated 2nd and
3rd homology.  I guess even easier is $B\mathbb R$, which is trivial,
vs $B\mathbb R_\delta$, with homology rank $2^\omega$ in every dimension.

Comment: Arg, lost my comment. @Bill, Sean. Thanks. I was getting stuck on that $G$ (from which we get $BG$) is a priori a topological group, but now I read all the comments again....

Comment: Theorem B in the paper
On the integral homology of finitely-presented groups
G. Baumslag, E. Dyer, and C. F. Miller
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 4 (1981), 321-324.
says roughly that for any recursively enumerable sequence of abelian groups $A_i$ with $A_1$, $A_2$ finitely generated, there exists a finitely presented group $G$ in which $H_n(G)=A_n$.
More precisely, each $A_i$ must have a presentation  of form $(X:R)_{ab}$, where $R$ is a free basis of the subgroup of FreeAb$(X)$ that it generates, the whole sequence of presentations must be r.e.

Comment: If a finite group has vanishing homology in all degrees, it is trivial. There should be an earlier reference, but Quillen's ICM address on group cohomology announces that for element $g\in G$, `$H^*(G)\to H^*(<g>)$` is nontrivial. I very much doubt that there is a uniform $n$ so that if a finite group has vanishing cohomology in degrees less than $n$, that it vanishes, but I can't give you any examples of groups with large vanishing ranges.

Comment: Just for the record: This question was posed ("an obvious question to ask") by A.Adem on page 810 of his 1997 paper 
[here](http://www.ams.org/notices/199707/adem.pdf). 

Answer (score 26):

Here is an approach to try to answer this question.
To show the  affirmative side 
[there is an N] look at the prime two and at swans argument that for a finite group with a two primary subgroup the cohomology mod two must be nonzero in infinitely many dimensions. I tried but didn't find it. if that results in a finite N with nonzero cohomology for all finte groups with a two primary part  the problem is solved. because if the two primary component is absent, the group is solvable and N=1 results in non zero homology.
On the other hand, to show the negative side, there is no such N. if swans argument does not yield such a concrete N for the prime two then one might well believe there is no such N, and that a string of examples  might be constructed by thinking about the proof of swan's theorem.

Comment: Wow, welcome to MO, prof. Sullivan! I will look into this.