# $G$ uncountable implies $K(G,1)$ is not a finite CW complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology, cw-complexes

I have read that $H^i(K(\mathbb{R},1)$) has rank $2^\omega$ for any $i\in \mathbb{N}$ (see Thurston's comment here [Nontrivial finite group with trivial group homologies?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52552/nontrivial-finite-group-with-trivial-group-homologies#comment130307_52552)) therefore $K(\mathbb{R},1)$ is not a finite CW complex and even the $n$-skeleton is not finite for any $n$.

On the other hand there are infinite (discrete) Lie groups $\pi$, such that $K(\pi,1)$ is finite. For example  consider $\pi = \pi_1 (E)$ where $E\subset \mathbb{S}^3$ is the knot exterior of a knot.
This seems to be a rather lucky case as we know that $K(F,1)$ is non finite for any discrete *finite* group $F$.

This made me wonder if the following is true:

> Is $K(G,1)$ an infinite CW complex for any $G$ Lie group of dimension greater than 1?
>
> What are other examples of $G$ such that  $K(G,1)$ is finite?

Note: infinite CW complex is the same as being non compact.

Comment: I think you're looking for [groups of type F](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finiteness_properties_of_groups).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any finite CW-complex $X$ and any basepoint $x \in X$, the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x)$ is finitely presented. (This is a consequence of the Seifert-van Kampen theorem.) In particular, the group itself is a quotient of a finitely generated free group, and hence must be a countable set.

However, if $G$ is a Lie group of positive dimension, then the underlying set of $G$ is uncountable. Therefore, no $K(G,1)$ can have the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex.

Comment: Thank you Tyler, do you know of other interesting classes of groups (a part from knot exteriors) that have finite $K(\pi,1)$?

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain I'm afraid that the examples in the page that Steve D linked to above (esp. torsion-free, finitely-generated nilpotent or hyperbolic groups) cover most of the examples that I know.

Comment: I think you should add that you consider $K(G^\delta,1)$, that is, $G$ is equipped with the discrete topology (which it is typically not if called a Lie group of positive dimension). Otherwise, I would not even know what $K(G,1)$ was supposed to mean.

Comment: @SebastianGoette sorry maybe I am missing something, doesn't the definition of $K(G,1)$ depend just on the group structure of $G$?

Comment: The definition says $\pi_1(K(G,1))\cong G$ and $\pi_k(K(G,1))=0$ otherwise. Now everything hinges on your understanding of "$\cong$". If you say "Lie group of positive dimension", I think that you want the group with its topology and differentiable structure. On the other, $\pi_1(X)$ is classically just a discrete group. But there might be a context where the functor $\pi_1$ can take values in groups with additional structure (in which case $K(G,1)$ should be related to the classifying space $BG$ in that category). I just wanted to avoid any misunderstandings.